# Android- My pictures are overwriting each other

Tags: java, android, camera

I'm a beginner android developer.I have made an android application that takes a photo and saves it into my gallery. However once I take a second photo it overwrites the first. Here is my code.

```
static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
private static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 0;
public void onClickbtnCamera(View v)
{
    Intent imageIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date(0));
    Uri uriSavedImage=Uri.fromFile(new File("/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera","QR_"+timeStamp+ ".png"));
    imageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
    startActivityForResult(imageIntent, 1); 
}
```

Basically I need the QR to add a number each time a photo is taking e.g. first photo (QR_) second photo (QR_1) third photo (QR_2). Thanks

Comment: `new Date(0)` are you not creating the same date each time? According to the [spec](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html) createing a `Date()` with no arguments returns the current time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing `new Date(0)` to `new Date()`.

You're always using 1 January 1970 to create your timestamp, which means they always come out the same. With this change, you'll always use the current timestamp. As long as you don't generate two pictures within the same second, they'll never clash.

(If you're worried about taking photos faster than one per second, you could always include milliseconds in your date format.)

Comment: When I change it to new Date() I get the fallowing error the constructor Date() is undefined any idea on how to fix this issue.

Comment: Import Util package for Date, not SQL package

Comment: @CraigGallagher if you found the answer useful, please do click the tick to mark as accepted answer. It gives you some rep too.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make sure that timestamp is differenet every time if not then generate random string using any random alogirithm and attach to timestamp.